# Is there a way to catch all un-handled error on Google App Engine in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to catch all un-handled errors in my app engine application, is there a solution that would allow me to do this with some kind of universal error handler or filter solution?

I know struts has a global error handler, but I am looking for something that doesn't require implementing anything too heavy in order to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: not sure if that applies to app engine but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548487/java-global-exception-handler

Comment: By errors, do you mean standard Java exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a filter.

This looks like a decent solution.

[how do I catch errors globally, log them and show user an error page in J2EE app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410808/how-do-i-catch-errors-globally-log-them-and-show-user-an-error-page-in-j2ee-app)